# Rails/Passenger: no such file to load -- money (MissingSourceFile)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, passenger, ruby-enterprise-edition

I am attempting to deploy a Rails application (which works fine in development) onto a production server. I have installed and configured Apache, Passenger, and the necessary gems. After I restart apache and navigate to the server, I get the following error:

```
Exception PhusionPassenger::UnknownError in PhusionPassenger::Railz::ApplicationSpawner (no such file to load -- money (MissingSourceFile))
```

`gem list money` shows:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

money (3.0.5)
```

An `irb` session on the server:

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'rubygems'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> require 'money'
=> true
```

The gem is required in `config/environment.rb`:

```
require 'money'
```

What's going on here?

**Edit:** The gem was installed as root:

```
# ls -l /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/money-3.0.5/lib
total 8
drwx------ 2 root root 4096 Sep  2 10:26 money
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1284 Sep  2 10:26 money.rb
```

**Edit 2:** After having no success with that roadblock, I realized that Passenger is sort of made to go along with Ruby Enterprise Edition, so I tried installing that. Afterwards, I used Ruby Enterprise's version of gem to install all the required gems. Now when I restart apache and navigate to my server, I get:

```
Exception LoadError in PhusionPassenger::Railz::ApplicationSpawner (no such file to load -- logger)
```

I have no problem requiring logger in either the old or new versions of Ruby:

```
# which irb
/usr/bin/irb
# irb
irb(main):001:0> require 'logger'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> exit
# /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.02/bin/irb 
irb(main):001:0> require 'logger'
=> true
```

Something must be going on with paths or permissions, but I followed the instructions in both the Passenger and Ruby Enterprise Edition installers exactly. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for your help. We investigated some more and found some of the required files (the gems themselves, I believe) were installed with the wrong permissions (not readable by the user that runs Apache/Passenger). I'm not sure why that happened, as they were installed the normal way as root (maybe some non-standard umask was the issue?), but changing permissions on those files fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Apache/Passenger runs the ruby process as root (or www-data), make sure you didn't install the Gem in a local repository.

You probably need to become superuser before installing the gem.

---

**Answer 2:**

The correct way to require a Gem is not using require, but using

```
config.gem "money"
```

Comment: I edited my post. The gem was installed as root and seems to be world-readable.

Comment: Thanks. The money gem documentation (http://money.rubyforge.org/) says to use `require 'money'`. Replacing the require in my environment.rb with `config.gem "money"` causes Passenger to give me the error: `undefined local variable or method `config' for main:Object`. Also, I should mention everything works fine in my development environment with the same code.

Answer (score 1):

are you using the same version of ruby for both?

Comment: maybe use passenger 3 and see if it has the same problem?

Comment: This has to be a permissions or path problem, I'd think... I'd rather stay with the current stable version of Passenger.